# how do i choose which program to archive from xcode IOS as i have two main files in my flutter app?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, testflight

I have a flutter app with two main.dart files. One is main_prod.dart and the other is main_dev.dart. I can run the application through both of these files which have different configuartions. I am planning on uploading both to testflight, but cant find a way to choose the one i want to upload.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:

You go on the "Generated" file and switch FLUTTER_TARGET=path to main.prod or main.dev here

[image]

Comment: did you create a dev and a prod version of Generated?